# Does the Invisibility spell end on a mystic if they use their abilities?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, invisibility, mystic

It's specifically stated that psionic abilities do not count as spells (thus, it's possible to use one as an action and another as a bonus action in the same turn).

A [duergar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/dwarf#GrayDwarfDuergar) (dwarf subrace) player character can cast the *invisibility* spell on themself (once per long rest). If I am a duergar mystic and cast *invisibility* on myself, do my psionic abilities cause the *invisibility* spell to end?

Comment: Are you asking about the Unearthed Arcana playtest version of the mystic class? (If so, which one - [this one](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf)?) ...Also, is there anything specific to duergar about this situation? It seems like the question would be the same regardless of how you're casting the *invisibility* spell, given that the potentially relevant restriction is part of the spell description and not specific to the racial trait. (I suppose that learning the *invisibility* spell would otherwise require multiclassing... Though someone else could cast it on them.)

Comment: Also: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

## Only if they use the ability to attack.

As you've noticed, mystic abilities don't count as spells. As such, they're not subject to the same restrictions as spells. Just like a monk can use Step of the Wind and a druid can Wildshape without breaking invisibility, so can a mystic manifest a power.

However, some mystic abilities involve making an attack roll. This involves a certain amount of interpretation, because "an attack" in D&D terms can mean either the attack action (a specific action that neither casting a spell or manifesting a mystic power counts as) or making an attack roll - ie a d20 roll with an attack bonus against a creature's AC.

The base rules define an attack thusly:

> If there’s ever any question whether something you’re doing counts as an Attack, the rule is simple: if you’re Making an Attack roll, you’re Making an Attack.

So using a mystic power that triggers an attack roll is making an attack, and would end invisibility.